# Round Down Current_Timestamp to Nearest Half Hour in Snowflake/SQL

Tags: timestamp, rounding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to round CURRENT_TIMESTAMP down to the nearest half hour in Snowflake.  In SQL, the code below would round a timestamp of '2021-01-01 10:35:00' to '2021-01-01 10:30:00' or '2021-01-01 17:20:00' to '2021-01-01 17:00:00', however, this syntax doesn't work in Snowflake.  Does anyone know how to do this in Snowflake?

SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, GETDATE())/30*30, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform to seconds from epoch, divide by 1800, round, and bring back to timestamp:

```sql
select to_timestamp(
  round(
    date_part(epoch_second, current_timestamp())/1800
  )*1800) nearest_half_hour  

# 2021-02-27T01:30:00Z
```

Or any arbitrary timestamp:

```sql
select to_timestamp(
  round(
    date_part(epoch_second, to_timestamp('2020-10-10 17:51:01'))/1800
  )*1800) nearest_half_hour    

# 2020-10-10T18:00:00Z
```

Comment: This actually rounds up or down to the nearest half hour. To round down you can change your expression to use `floor` instead of `round`. The time_slice function will always round down to bucket the times from 1970-01-01.

Comment: Correct @GregPavlik! I read "round" initially (instead of "round down"), and `floor()` will do that. Looking at your answer - `time_slice` is even better (but less standard in the SQL world)

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in function in Snowflake for this called `time_slice`.

```
select time_slice(current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz, 30, 'MINUTE');
```

Comment: Thank you, Greg!  That rounded down perfectly.  Cheers!!