# snowflake: counting no.of rows present in an hour as single row

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lag

I have a user record for every login he does. I need to count how many times user has logged in. But I also need to consider that even though how many times a user logged in half an hour, i need to count as 1 time.

```
USER_ID  TIMESTAMP
A1        2021-03-10 10:00:00
A1        2021-03-10 10:01:00
A1        2021-03-10 10:05:00
A1        2021-03-10 10:15:00
A1        2021-03-10 10:32:00
A1        2021-03-10 11:02:00
A1        2021-03-11 12:00:00
A2        2021-03-10 10:01:00
```

```
USER_ID     TIMESTAMP
A1            4
A2            1
```

I am not able to figure out how to use lag and lead with the situation. Any help would be appreciatable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, count(distinct(date_trunc('hour',timestamp)::text||iff(minute(timestamp)>30,'_1','_0'))) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

so this works by truncating to the hour and turning it into a string then add a suffix per half hour. Not the cleanest, but it should work.

Ah this question asked h[ow to get time in 30 minutes truncations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394758/round-down-current-timestamp-to-nearest-half-hour-in-snowflake-sql)

Of which the time_slice was a nice answer:

```
SELECT user_id, count(distinct(time_slice(timestamp, 30, 'MINUTE'))) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id, ORDER BY user_id;
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide the start time in time_slice? because i want the session period (hour) to start when the first time user logged in. For user A2, counting starts at 10:01:00

Comment: oh, are not wanting rigid windows, but from the first... and then to find the distinct batches from there... ah. at which point a javascript table function will be the simplest way.

Comment: @kavya . . . That is not the question you asked here.  I would suggest that you accept this answer and then ask a *new* question (and I don't think a javascript function is needed).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe `But I also need to consider that even though how many times a user logged in half an hour, i need to count as 1 time.` is the part where they are asking for windowed based on values, but as she is noting that is not possible with LAG.